# How do I determine whether a Criteria instance already has a Subcriteria?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am writing a search interface where the user can select from the fields of several different entities. This a Spring MVC (3.0.5) application using Hibernate 3

My DAO class must be able to respond flexibly to these requests. I would like to use an approach like this:

```
critAliases = new ArrayList<String>();
...

Session session = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
crit = session.createCriteria(RootEntity.class);

// selected search options from user
for ( SearchOption opt: searchOptionList ) {
    if ( ! critAliases.contains(opt.getAlias()) ) {
        crit.addAlias(opt.getEntityName(), opt.getAlias(), opt.getJoinType());
        critAliases.add(opt.getAlias());
    }
}
```

Note that I have to keep track of the aliases with an instance variable

```
List<String> critAliases
```

in my DAO class.

I would prefer to ask the Criteria instance if it already contains a Subcriteria that matches my opt.getAlias() string. Criteria interface exposes a getAlias() method which will do for the root entity, but no method to inspect or list the Criteria's aliases.

Does anybody have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current solution is best one.
Although CriteriaImpl has a method to iterate the created Subcriteria (createAlias will create a Subcriteria) this method is not provided by the interface (Criteria) so using that would not be 'nice'. Even if it were I would still opt for your solution (although I would recommend using a Set instead of List for this scenario).