# tracing sources of queries in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, log4j, hql

In Hibernate is there a way to trace which line of *source code* does each of the generated queries come from? I have been using debugging tools to print out nicely formatted HQL queries in the server log, but I would like to know how I can trace where in the source code such queries were generated.

Comment: How are you composing your queries? String concatenation? Or Criteria API?

Comment: @carbontax: I have been using the criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Criteria API and I think I know why you are asking this. The problem is that it is very difficult to inspect the Criteria instance before calling the list() method. For example, this question deals with inspecting a hibernate Criteria instance to see which aliases have been defined on it.

[How do I determine whether a Criteria instance already has a Subcriteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806556/how-do-i-determine-whether-a-criteria-instance-already-has-a-subcriteria)

Perhaps there is a clue in this for you, because one suggestion was to use Hibernate's CriteriaImpl class, even though it is a non-standard approach.

Does JPA2 Criteria address this problem?